# Как значение из INPUT динамический отобразить в другом элементе через AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="uk-input uk-form-width-small" name="summa" required pattern="^[ 0-9]+$" placeholder="Сумма" maxlength="6">
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
<span class="uk-text-lowercase th-text-summa">Примерное значение <span class="summa_one"></span></span>
```

Как числовое значение из `input` динамический отобразить в `span` через AJAX при этом увеличилось значение на единицу, а после нажатия на кнопку `<button type="submit">Отправить</button>`, и значение `input` и текст `span` отправить в базу данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если можете инпуту дать type number, то так

```
var $form = $('form'),
    $input = $('.uk-input'),
    $span = $('.summa_one');

$form.on('input', $input, function(){
  var input_val = +$input.val();
  $span.html( (input_val > 0) ? input_val + 1 : '' );
})

$form.submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // тут можно запустить какой-нибудь лофадер на время аякса
  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',  // куда - путь к файлу
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {
      input_val: $input.val(),
      span_val: $span.html()
    },
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    // data - тут данные с ответа сервера
    console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function() { 
    console.log("error"); // это выполнится если ошибка
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log("complete"); // это выполнится всегда
     // тут можно скрыть лоадер
  });

})
```

Если input type text, то можно добавить проверку в keyup

```
$form.on('input', $input, function(){
  var input_val = +$input.val();
  if(!input_val) {
    $input.val('');
    return false;
  }
  $span.html( (input_val > 0) ? input_val + 1 : '' );
})
```

Comment: Событие `keyup` хорошо, но оно может не сработать в мобильных браузерах, а также в случае вставки из буфера обмена или `drag&drop`. Лучше заменить на событие `input`

Comment: Согласен. поправил